# Error when adding s.frameworks 'XCTest' to podspec dyld: Library not loaded: rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest

Tags: swift, xcode8, xctest, cocoapods-1.2

I have a CocoaPod which uses the XCTest framework. To import `XCTest` to the pod, I added `s.frameworks = 'XCTest'` to the **.podspec** file.

I am now able to import XCTest to the pod classes but when trying to run the Example project, I am getting the following error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest
>
> Referenced from: /Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEVICE_UUID/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/ID/TestPod_Example.app/Frameworks/TestPod.framework/TestPod
>
> Reason: image not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution, when adding `XCTest` framework in the **podspec**, make sure to add it to your UITesting and Testing targets only in the **Podfile**.. This is because `XCTest` cannot run on a developed target, only on a test targets.

In your **Podfile**

```
target 'MyProjectTestTarget' do
   pod 'PodFramework that includes XCTest as a dependency'
end
```

Comment: Hi, can you give an example what you mean by "add it to your UITesting and Testing targets only in the Podfile"?

Comment: Sure @BadmintonCat I amended the answer. If you can bump up my question and answer, that would be awesome! ;)